# Why one cannot download the drivers of the Android OS like we do in our pc's

Tags: kernel

I know that i sound kind of a noob but i had this question from the day i started tweaking my phone .I know that without kernel sources it is very hard to get drivers for the phone for the sake of custom ROM support but my question is why can't i just download the drivers from the manufacturer website as i download for my pc .i can install the desired android version i want and if the driver is available for the respective Android version i could simply install it as an application as i would do it in my PC.what exactly the kernel sources contain.

Comment: PC or Windows OS?

Comment: linux users don't bother about the drivers because they are already embedded in it.

Answer (score 0):

sadly if it was an application like on the PC there would be billions of pirated versions and you would have to bother to search through all of them to find the official one. If there is an update for your phone it will appear as a notification and it will inform you that it is available.

Comment: Not the answer i was looking for ,First of all Android is a open source so why couldn't google follow the desktop way of installing the OS in any smartphones with minimum requirements.for drivers, what i mean is that if i had to find the drivers for my camera i could simply go to the manufacturer website,enter the sensor model and download the drivers for it so that there is no need for the binaries from the OEM side which will easily eliminate the poor camera performance after installing custom ROM's such as cyanogenmod which basically doesn't have very good image processing algorithm .

Comment: Android is an open source, I agree but the drivers are sent to the user when they are available and custom ROM's can make the camera's perfomance go from bad to absolute dog sheit. There is a way to install drivers via PC tho. You will need to plug your usb cable into the pc then to your phone, download the drivers onto the pc and then transfer to the phone and run them from the phone, or you could try finding the pc companion for that phone and install drivers for your phone on the pc.

Answer (score 0):

@vishalaestro

Android doesn't work like that, many if not most "drivers" are closed source proprietary binaries and shared libraries, as well as some firmware files in kernel sources. You can't flip drivers on Android devices like you can in Windows as those "drivers" are tightly built into the Android system, tied to numerous sevices and many standard libraries as well. Your customization options without rom hopping or upgrading API level [if that firmware exists],
comes with rooting your devices, dumping you stock recovery, disassembling the image and beginning to construct your device tree , then getting hold of android source code build system and having a ball!
Should be doesn't factor into it. it is what it is.

BUT, getting hold of the kernel source and "correcting" shortcomings has alot more possibilities. check out the forums on xda [the good ones anyway]
and you'll see what goes into the process.